# how to add date field in html showing like a calender

Tags: php, html

i am new to html and php i have created one railway ticket booking page in html .in that form page there are option where the user going to fill like start station,reach station  and date, so how can i show date ,that is when the user click the date means it shows like a calender and the user select the appropriate date where planned to travel and i want to show next three month date from the current date like a calender. because we give permission to book the ticket before three month..so any one help me doing this in html..
and when the user select the date how can I get that selected date..

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done in HTML alone, you need to use javascript, or even better, jQuery, which is a javascript library designed to simplify the creation of client-side scripts.

When using jQuery, as you can probably suspect, a lot of things already exist, including a date picker.

You can find more info on this page : http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/‎

I also encourage you to check out the other contents the jQuery UI site, as they are really useful to easily design richer forms.